# How can make two results on one uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

Example:

```
NSArray *result = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", nil];
```

I want to show like the image: [Image Link](http://postimg.org/image/59soj1pjb/)

Can I make it with a `UITableView`?
Or do I need to use a `UICollectionView`? Or a `UICollectionView` then `UITableView` in a `UIView`?

I hope someone provide a solution to me.

Objective-C be best, thank you!

Comment: Please explain what you really want. A and B in the first cell and C and D in the second and E and F in the third cell etc.?

Comment: After playing around with a story board for a while the easiest way to do this (I think) will be to create a Custom Table View cell that has a second content view that will create the look of a second cell but not actually having to manage a split row

Comment: @HermannKlecker A and B in the first cell and C and D in the second is right, but E in third, F in 4th, G in 5th....etc

Comment: @Braains But I need didSelectRowAtIndexPath function, how can create 2 cell result in a cell

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is difficutl then. You could use buttons in the cell to determine, which item was hit. But then it gets rather complicated. Therefore I suggest to use a collection view instead. It is made for that and its usage is similar to the usage of tables.

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thanks, I will try to use collectionview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either with a `UICollectionView` and create a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` or with a `UITableView` and two different `UITableViewCell`'s

However, option 2 will give you a headache keeping your dataSource synced with your `NSIndexPath`'s.

Comment: If no other better solutions, I will accept this answer on Friday

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

First:
You can do that with a collection.

Second:
You can do that with a straight table if you create an array of arrays. The inner array has one or two object only. Like.

```
 [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"A", @"B"], @[@"C", @"D"], @[@"E", @"F"], @[@"G"], nil];
```

And of course you would have to use some custom layout of your cells.

BTW you could use `@[]` instead of `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...]` anyway.

Third: 
You can just use your array and a regular table with a custom layout of the cells. And create the datasource accordingly. So `numberOfRowsInSection` would return your array length / 2 etc. pp.

Comment: Thanks! But I mean is the first four results will show two in one cell, other results will show one in one cell (like common tableview cell)